# functions with arguments in Django's template

Tags: django, templates

I have formally constructed the function in my `models.py` file :

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.template.defaultfilters import date as datefilter
from django.utils import translation

def date_customerprofile(language):
    now_ = datetime.today()
    if language == 'English':
        translation.activate('en')
        return datefilter(now_, 'l, F j, Y')
    else:
        translation.activate('fr')
        return datefilter(now_, 'l, j F Y')
```

I would like to use this function in a template, but it is unclear it will work fine. I'd like to use `{{ date_customerprofile('French') }}`, but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to use {{ date_customerprofile('French') }}, but it didn't work

Of course. Django's template language is NOT Python. It's smart enough to [apply some lookup rules on objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/language/#variables) but does not allow functions or method calls - and yes, this is by design:

> If you have a background in programming, or if you’re used to languages which mix programming code directly into HTML, you’ll want to bear in mind that the Django template system is not simply Python embedded into HTML. This is by design: the template system is meant to express presentation, not program logic.

*https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/language/*

The solution here is to [create a custom templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/). Also note that `translation.activate` will change the active language for the remaining of the request/response cycle which is certainly not what you want - using the `translation.override` context manager is certainly a better idea.

Finally it looks like you're reinventing the square wheel - the correct language should already be activated for the current request so instead of manually forcing it (with a non standard language code), you should probably just use the current one to select the appropriate date format.

Comment: Ok, I understand your point. I know what is a templatetag, but it is unclear how to implement that. Could you give me a example how to implement my templatetag? ... I will accept your answer.

Comment: There are quite some example in the documentation I linked to. For what you want a mere `simple_tag` will be enough so it shouldn't take more than a dozen minutes to figure it out, really. I suggest you first give it a try by yourself and post back here (editing your post) for more help if needed.

Comment: Sorry, but it is a bit hard to understand. Could you give me an example. In fact, it's been a month I work with python and django. So it is not always easy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43120100/create-template-tags-from-the-current-function/43121032?noredirect=1#comment73323870_43121032

Comment: Sorry but the answer you accepted is just a total WTF. And you still didn't post what __you__ tried, just reposted the same question with some added copy/paste from my above answer. You're not going to learn anything that way, really.

Comment: I tried a lot of thing before asking the question. At my level, it is pretty hard to do something relevant. That's why I asked some more help.