# Create template tags from the current function

Tags: python, django, templatetags

I have formally constructed the function in my `models.py` file :

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.template.defaultfilters import date as datefilter
from django.utils import translation

def date_customerprofile(language):
    now_ = datetime.today()
    if language == 'English':
        translation.activate('en')
        return datefilter(now_, 'l, F j, Y')
    else:
        translation.activate('fr')
        return datefilter(now_, 'l, j F Y')
```

I know Django's template language is NOT Python, so we can't write `{{ customer.date_customerprofile('French') }}`.

The solution here is to create a custom templatetag. Also note that `translation.activate` will change the active language for the remaining of the request/response cycle - using the `translation.override` context manager is certainly a better idea. As I am not an expert with templatetags, could anyone be able to show me how could I create it in taking into consideration the above function?

I think we could use the following question to do such thing [How to format date in different languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369493/how-to-format-date-in-different-languages)

Could I use context manager : [Django switching, for a block of code, switch the language so translations are done in one language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258715/django-switching-for-a-block-of-code-switch-the-language-so-translations-are-d/10385085#10385085)?

Thanks!

In fact, I would like to return in the template as output the current date in French 'Jeudi, 30 mars 2017' or the current date in English `Thursday, March 30, 2017`.

**P.S.** Please tell me if the question is unclear.

This is an example of Django's template :

```
{% load i18n %}
{% load date %}

{{ customer.civil_title }}{{ user.get_full_name }}                                         
{{ customer.civic_number }}, {{ customer.street }}
{{ customer.rough_location }}

{# customer. date_customerprofile('English') #}


                           7 DAYS NOTICE

Subject:  Overdue account with ...
Client id : {{ customer.id }}

Hello {{ customer.civil_title }}{{ user.get_full_name }},

This notice serves to inform you that your payments with Gestion Multi Finance Inc. are pending. Your file has been transferred to our collection service. The balance of your loan is now:  {{ customer.current_balance }}.

We are asking you to communicate with us without delay, by phone at: 1-855-... ext. 324 or by email at: ... to find a payment solution in order to regulate your situation. If this does not happen, we will be forced to send you a notice of acceleration of the process and transfer your file to our judiciary collection service, with authority to take the necessary steps in the collection process. These steps can include the seizure of salary, but we prefer to avoid these measures.

 Also, it is important to remember that at the time of the loan, you signed a contract in which you agreed to respect the payments. Unfortunately, you have no respected this agreement.

 Ignore this notice if an agreement has already been reached.

Cordially,

{{ email.footer.txt }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now we've seen the total nonsense answer, here's the no-nonsense one:

In your `yourapp/templatetags/yourapptags.py` module:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

DATE_FORMATS = {
    "en":  "l, F j, Y",
    "fr": "l, j F Y"
}

DEFAULT_LANG = 'fr'

@register.simple_tag
def localdate(lang=DEFAULT_LANG):
    fmt = DATE_FORMATS.get(lang, DATE_FORMATS[DEFAULT_LANG])
    now = datetime.now()
    with translation.override(lang):
        return datefilter(now, fmt)
```

Then in your template:

```
{% load "yourapptags" %}

<p>EN : {% localdate 'en' %}</p>
<p>FR : {% localdate 'fr' %}</p>
```

Note that this is for forcing date formatting / localisation in a given locale whatever the current locale is which in this case seems quite weird to me.

If what you really want is just to display the current date formatted according to the current visitor's locale (cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference), you can just get rid of the `lang` argument and use `translation.get_language()` instead:

```
@register.simple_tag
def localdate():
    lang = translation.get_language()
    fmt = DATE_FORMATS.get(lang, DATE_FORMATS[DEFAULT_LANG])
    now = datetime.now()
    return datefilter(now, fmt)
```

Also note that l10n formats files provided by Django already have [some date formats defined and that you can override them](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/formatting/#creating-custom-format-files).

Comment: I am using a template tag in a Django's template, so this writting`<p>EN : {% localdate 'en' %}</p>` is not well received.  Even if your answer is probably better, because it is quite short and compact, I must use this writtring `{{ customer|tmpl_date_customerprofile:'French' }}`. What are you suggest?

Comment: "{{ customer|tmpl_date_customerprofile:'French' }}" is not a template tag, it's a template variable with a filter applied on it. And I don't see any reason why you 'd "must use" one syntax over the other - but well, you didn't provide _any_ background to your question, did you ?

Comment: If you understand well, A Django's template is a bit different of a html template. I will add a picture in my question in two minutes

Comment: In fact, there is a part in html and another part in non-html... weird!

Comment: Django templates actually have nothing to do with html - they generate whatever kind of text format you want. Your template is obviously used for emails, so having a html and a pure text versions is quite common.

Comment: How could I use `<p>EN : {% localdate 'en' %}</p>` in the 'test format' so that it could fit. Does this writting `{{ En : localdate 'en' }}` or  `EN : {% localdate 'en' ` could work well?

Comment: Err... Given the example template it's obviously a paid job. If you're not even able to answer this last question then you're obviously doing the wrong job - and I'm not going to to your job for free, sorry.

Comment: Could you at least tell me why I have `ValueError: Invalid arguments provided to simple_tag`

Comment: A mistake in my code sorry - fixed it in the answer.

Comment: name='localdate' and it is override, not activate. Otherwise, it works well

Comment: Yeah I should not answer here while waiting for the full test suite to run ;)